# Using the TFS 2010 API to subscribe to Workspace Events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to write some code that monitors the TFS workspace(s) on my local workstation but at the moment I'm having problems getting the events to fire.

For example if I map a new folder in my workspace I want to subscribe to the versionControl.UpdatedWorkspace event, and if I do a “get” I want to map to the versionControl.Getting event. The code below is a console application that I think should work, but when I do a get nothing happens. Does anyone know how to successfully subscribe to these events?

VS2010, TFS 2010, WinXP SP3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace TestEventHanling
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri serverUri = new Uri(@"http://TfsServer:8080/tfs/collection");

            using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri, CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials))
            {

                VersionControlServer versionControl = (VersionControlServer)collection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
                versionControl.UpdatedWorkspace += new WorkspaceEventHandler(OnUpdatedWorkspace);
                versionControl.Getting += new GettingEventHandler(OnGetting);

                Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit.");
                while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;

            }
        }


        internal static void OnUpdatedWorkspace(object sender, WorkspaceEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (WorkingFolder wf in e.Workspace.Folders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Workspace updated {0}", wf.ServerItem);
            }
        }

        internal static void OnGetting(Object sender, GettingEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting: {0}, status: {1}", e.TargetLocalItem, e.Status);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding are that these are events that are on your local instance of VersionControlServer.  That is to say, they will fire when you act on that instance in your code.

For example, if, somewhere else in your code, you updated a workspace, then the `UpdatedWorkspace` handler would fire.

There's a smaller set of events that you can subscribe to server-side (check-in, builds, etc.), but I'm not sure  that you can monitor what's happening on the server through the VersionControlServer class.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought they would fire when I manipulate the workspace or do a get outside of the running code (e.g. from VS), similar to the way the events in the FileSystemWatcher behave. I'll have a dig around and look for the servers side events, and see if these meet my requirements.

Comment: I've had a look around the API and I don't think there is anything that will do what I want. Oh well, back to the drawing board

Comment: OK. I have worked with this sample of code and it has worked as well as described.
However, I need to update some information in my application's Database where anychange happens on the ServerSide (TeamWebAccess or the WorkItem is updated out of the application in .net). Thanks in advice.

Comment: This has to do with the eventing server in TFS, not the events in the client object model.  You should ask a separate question.