# How to check when TFS Workspace.Get method is complete?

Tags: c#, tfs, build, workspace, getlatest

I am using the `Workspace` class from the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` namespace to get the latest code for a particular branch from a Team Foundation Server.

```
workspace.Get(new string[] { SelectedRelease.ServerPath }, VersionSpec.Latest,
RecursionType.Full, GetOptions.GetAll);
```

After I get the latest code, I build the relevant solution programmatically. The code can be found in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357644/how-can-i-programmatically-build-my-solution-files-from-c-code).

My question is 'how can I find out when the Workspace.Get method is complete? I can't build it until it has finished downloading. I thought about monitoring the solution folder, but I don't know which order the files are built in.

Comment: This question may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184252/using-the-tfs-2010-api-to-subscribe-to-workspace-events

Comment: Thank you @Jamie Dixon, that was just what I was after. Can you please paste your comment into an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may be of use to you:

[Using the TFS 2010 API to subscribe to Workspace Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184252/using-the-tfs-2010-api-to-subscribe-to-workspace-events)

Comment: Thank you @Jamie Dixon, that was just what I was after. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not asynchronous.  As soon as it returns, your get has finished.

If you want to listen for completion in another thread (and use TFS's event system to do so instead of rolling your own), you can hook up a GettingEventHandler to your VersionControlClient.

Comment: It is asynchronous. My program continues while it gets the files... why else would I post this question?

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing some other behavior?  For example, Workspace.Get will return immediately if you specify an invalid server path (there's nothing to do.)  What does the resultant GetStatus look like?

Comment: On further inspection, I believe that you could be correct and wholeheartedly apologise for my previous comment. In fact, this does explain some perculiar behaviour the program was having, so thanks. +1

Comment: No worries at all!  It would have been more helpful if I'd mentioned something about why it might not do any work in my first post, but I hadn't considered the missing (or lack of permissions) on a server path.